# How to make gradle run terminate if the underlying Java process is termianted?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project where I apply the Gradle `application` plugin. My problem is that it doesn't terminate even if the underlying process terminates: if I run this:

```
gradle run
```

with a `main` which only contains a `System.exit(0);` the program terminates but `Gradle` doesn't. How do I force the Gradle process to terminate when the underlying Java program terminates?

*Edit:* I Know I can call `gradle --stop` but that would require another process and it is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

`gradle run` terminates when your application terminates. However, if you use gradle [daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) (enabled by default in later versions), the daemon still prevails.

The easiest solution is to pass `--no-daemon` to the gradle CLI. You can also configure it in the properties.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. Is it possible that the `application` plugin messes it up?

Comment: Highly unlikely, it's just a `JavaExec` task. You could try to attach a debugger or JVisualVM to the process to gather more information. Did you run `gradle --no-daemon run` (gradle parameters before task name)?

Comment: Is `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` appearing or is it stuck? Also did you ensure to stop all daemons before running your experiment?

Comment: There is no `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, it is stuck. I've stopped all daemons. Dont' worry, we solved this another way.

Comment: @AdamArold How did you solve it?

Comment: I don't remember it was years ago 

Answer (score 0):

kill the java process manually from cli. linux using `killall java`, windows using `taskkill /f /im java.exe`

for an example my script.cmd

```
@echo off

taskkill /f /im java.exe
call gradlew :app:assembleAarch64Release --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx1g -Xms300m"
taskkill /f /im java.exe
call gradlew :app:assembleArmRelease --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx1g -Xms300m"
taskkill /f /im java.exe
call gradlew :app:assembleX86Release --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx1g -Xms300m"
taskkill /f /im java.exe
call gradlew :app:assembleX86_64Release --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx1400m -Xms300m"
taskkill /f /im java.exe
```

it will kill java each finished task. to keep my pc performance